# Объясните процесс шифрования данных, поправьте мои представления об этом

Tags: шифрование

Читаю вот эту статью http://www.intuit.ru/studies/courses/108/108/lecture/3141

*Если А – открытое сообщение, В – закрытое сообщение ( шифр ) , f – правило шифрования, то f(A) = B.*

*Правила шифрования должны быть выбраны так, чтобы зашифрованное сообщение можно было расшифровать. Однотипные правила (например, все шифры типа шифра Цезаря, по которому каждый символ алфавита кодируется отстоящим от него на k позиций символом) объединяются в классы, и внутри класса определяется некоторый параметр (числовой, символьный табличный и т.д.), позволяющий перебирать (варьировать) все правила. Такой параметр называется шифровальным ключом. Он, как правило, секретный и сообщается лишь тому, кто должен прочесть зашифрованное сообщение (обладателю ключа ).*

Не могу понять, что за параметр ? Или понял : это алгоритм для выбора правил, которые будут применяться. Но почему тогда он может быть символьный, табличный..Значит не понял что то.. Написано, что если кто-то знает ключ, значит он может расшифровать, но а если он не знает правила шифрования? Вывод, ключ (некий параметр )включает в себя и  эти правила. В общем приведите пожалуйста пример. 
   *Имеются две большие группы шифров: шифры перестановки и шифры замены.*
А почему нет шифров удаления? Типо каждый пятый символ шифруемого файла удаляется. Или я снова что то не понял и написанное мной это всего лишь правило.

Comment: Насчет шифра удаления. Он ведь не обратимый получается. Если удалить каждый второй символ, если он окажется К, то как потом понять был там К или нет.  Никак.

Comment: Не даром при объяснении в статье все выражено математическими формулами. Предположим нам надо шифровать числа и алгоритм шифрования заключается просто в умножении этих чисел на какое то число. А ключ шифрования, как и показано в формулах это просто параметр функции шифрования, т.е. то самое число на которое надо умножать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Шифрование** - это **обратимое** преобразование информации. Преобразование производиться по определенному алгоритму (алгоритм шифрования). Так же существует алгоритм (алгоритм дешифрования), который позволяет восстановить оригинальную информацию из зашифрованной.

Если алгоритм не меняется, то надежность шифра зависит только от секретности алгоритма. Как только алгоритм попадет к другому человеку он сможет расшифровать всю зашифрованную информацию.

**Ключ** - это параметр, который позволяет "модифицировать" алгоритм шифрования. Для дешифрования надо знать не только алгоритм, но и ключ.

Для простоты можно представлять алгоритм шифрования в виде функции с двумя параметрами - ключ и открытый текст. `E(ключ, информация) = зашифрованная информация`

Поскольку сейчас часто используются открытые алгоритмы шифрования, то секретность шифра зависит не от алгоритма, а от ключа.

Так же существуют алгоритмы, которые имеют разные ключи для шифрования и дешифрования. Например, алгоритм шифрования шифрования [RSA](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA).

[Шифр Цезаря](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A8%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%80_%D0%A6%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8F) - это **подстановочный** шифр. При шифровании каждая буква исходного сообщения преобразовывается в другую букву. То есть происходит однозначная **подстановка**. **Ключом** в нем является число - это сдвиг исходной буквы в алфавите.

Другим известным **подстановочными** шифром является шифр из произведения [Пляшущие человечки](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%88%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B8). Каждой букве в нем соответсвует рисунок человечка.

Так же подстановочными шифрами без ключа можно считать:

- [Азбука Морзе](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%B7%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%9C%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B7%D0%B5)
- [Семафорная Азбука](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B0)

В **перестановочном** шифре буквы (сочетания букв) в исходном сообщении меняют местами по определенному алгоритму. Вы можете поменять местами четные и не четные буквы. Тогда **шифр** станет **ишрф**.

Еще одним примером **перестановочного** шифра является [Решётка Кардано](http://%D0%A0%D0%B5%D1%88%D1%91%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0%20%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE). Это листок бумаги с прорезями в определенных местах. Решетка накладывается на лист бумаги и в прорези пишут буквы (слова), потом решетку убирают и пустые места заполняют "мусором".

Шифра удаления не может быть, так как удаление - это необратимое преобразование.

Comment: Вы написали, что существуют алгоритмы, которые имеют разные ключи для шифрования.  Т.е. шифр известен,  так еще и ключи какие то известные? Или это просто типы ключей? Или вы имели ввиду один ключ составляется для шифрования,  а другой для дешифрования,  подобрать такие конечно сложнее,  но надежнее.  Так?

Comment: Но шифр азбуки морзе ведь известен. Это больше кодировка точками и тире.  А кодирование и шифрование разные вещи.  А вот уже набором букв кодируемыми морзе обозначают что то

Comment: я в ответе дал ссылку на алгоритм с двумя ключами. там два разных ключа:для кодирования используется один, а для декодирования другой. но лучше задайте отдельный вопрос. кодирование и шифрование - это преобразование информации, так что в некотором роде - это одно и тоже. даже UNICODE в некотором роде шифр.

Comment: Правильно ли я понимаю, что ключ нужен для удобства?  Благодаря нему не приходится передавать более громоздкие алгоритмы шифрования тому кому положено расшифровать,  а передается ключ. И еще,  если бы и алгоритм и ключ были секретны это значительно повысило бы безопасность , но для работы достаточно и удобнее алгоритмы держать открытыми

Comment: И еще, скажите какой алгоритм шифрования достаточен и какие используют для шифровки рекордов игры , которые не планируется передавать по сети.  И правильно ли я думаю, что Api  Гугл игры шифрует данные

Comment: не задавайте вопросы в комментариях. лучше задайте их отдельным вопросом. тогда их можно будет легче найти.